# IllegalStateException with StreamSupplier

Tags: java, java-8, illegalstateexception, option-type, java-stream

I have the following code to do different things in one stream.

```
  private void getBuildInformation(Stream<String> lines)
  {
    Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> lines;

    String buildNumber = null;
    String scmRevision = null;
    String timestamp = null;
    String buildTag = null;

      Optional<String> hasBuildNumber = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains(LogProps.PLM_BUILD)).findFirst();
      if (hasBuildNumber.isPresent())
      {
        buildNumber = hasBuildNumber.get();
        String[] temp = buildNumber.split("=");
        if (temp.length >= 2)
          buildNumber = temp[1].trim();
      }

      Optional<String> hasSCMRevision = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains(LogProps.SCM_REVISION_50)).findFirst();
      if (hasSCMRevision.isPresent())
      {
        scmRevision = hasSCMRevision.get();
        String[] temp = scmRevision.split(":");
        if (temp.length >= 4)
          scmRevision = temp[3].trim();
      }

      Optional<String> hasBuildTag = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains(LogProps.BUILD_TAG_50)).findFirst();
      if (hasBuildTag.isPresent())
      {
        buildTag = hasBuildTag.get();
        String[] temp = buildTag.split(":");
        if (temp.length >= 4)
          buildTag = temp[3].trim();
      }

      Optional<String> hasTimestamp = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains(LogProps.BUILD_TIMESTAMP_50)).findFirst();
      if (hasTimestamp.isPresent())
      {
        timestamp = hasTimestamp.get();
        String[] temp = timestamp.split(":");
        if (temp.length >= 4)
          timestamp = temp[3].trim();
      }
}
```

Now the problem is, if I call the first time

`Optional<String> hasBuildNumber = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains(LogProps.PLM_BUILD)).findFirst();`

it is working properly, but if I call the next

`Optional<String> hasSCMRevision = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains(LogProps.SCM_REVISION_50)).findFirst();`

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-21" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(AbstractPipeline.java:203)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:94)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$StatelessOp.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:618)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:163)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.filter(ReferencePipeline.java:162)
    at com.dscsag.dscxps.model.analysis.Analysis.getECTRBuildInformation(Analysis.java:205)
    at com.dscsag.dscxps.model.analysis.Analysis.parseLogFile(Analysis.java:153)
    at com.dscsag.dscxps.model.analysis.Analysis.analyze(Analysis.java:135)
    at com.dscsag.dscxps.model.XPSModel.lambda$startAnalysis$0(XPSModel.java:467)
    at com.dscsag.dscxps.model.XPSModel$$Lambda$1/12538894.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Since I read this page http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/ I think it should be working, cause the supplier provides new streams on `get()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you re-write your supplier as an anonymous pre-java 8 class. That would be equivalent to:

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = new Supplier<Stream<String>>() {
     @Override
     public Stream<String> get() {
         return lines;
     }
 };
```

Maybe here it becomes more obvious that you are returning the same stream instance each time you call `get` on your supplier (and hence the exception thrown on the second call because `findFirst` is a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)). You are not returning a brand new Stream.

In the webpage example you gave, the writer uses `Stream.of` which create a brand new Stream each time `get` is called, that's why it works.

AFAIK there is no way to duplicate a Stream from an existing one. So one workaround would be to pass the object from which the Stream comes in and then get the Stream in the supplier.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        getBuildInformation(Arrays.asList("TEST", "test"));
    }
    private static void getBuildInformation(List<String> lines) {
        Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> lines.stream();

        Optional<String> hasBuildNumber = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains("t")).findFirst();
        System.out.println(hasBuildNumber);

        Optional<String> hasSCMRevision = streamSupplier.get().filter(s -> s.contains("T")).findFirst();
        System.out.println(hasSCMRevision);

    }
}
```

Which output:

```
Optional[test]
Optional[TEST]
```

Since you get the lines from a Path object, handling the exception in the Supplier itself can come quite ugly so what you can do is to create an helper method that will handle the Exception to be catched, then it would be like this:

```
private static void getBuildInformation(Path path) {
    Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> lines(path);
    //do your stuff
}
private static Stream<String> lines(Path path) {
    try { 
        return Files.lines(path); 
    }
    catch (IOException e) { 
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Another problem is, that lines is populated with Files.lines(...). So how to achieve it with this?

Comment: @MarcelHöll You can pass the `Path` object to your method and do `() -> Files.lines(path);`